# The correct forms of verbs when the time is 'all something.'

Tags: grammar, verbs

A fill in the blank from a school's worksheet. What bothers me is the word 'all.' Does it matter in deciding the verbs in this blank?

> I ______ *(work)* on the project **all night.**

The confusion:

***Without any context,*** it could be *had been, have been, or simple past tense*. Say:

> I *had been working* on the project all night.
>  I *have been working* on the project all night. 
>  I *worked* on the project all night.

Who knows which night? Last night, the night last week, or the night last year? So with almost all the blanks there!

*Does the answer lie in the word **'all'?***

What am I missing? What could be the answer?

Comment: The presence or absence of an adverbial clause ***all** [day, night, etc.]* has no real bearing on whether to use a Perfect and/or Continuous form. Apart from the fact that *when in doubt you should always choose the simpler verb form,* your choices are primarily governed by the normal principles: (1) Use a Perfect form if the action is relevant to the *narrative reference time*, (2) Use the ***Past*** Perfect if that reference time is earlier than time of utterance, and (3) Use a continuous form to emphasise the *process* (rather than the "completion" of an action).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *if the action is relevant...if that reference time....* No *ifs and buts!* What could be the answers for the given blanks? There is nothing specified. I mean the time of utterance and so on. Why would I ask if sufficient information is given?